# Read() issue in network programming UNIX

Tags: c++, unix, networking

I am programming on 'Auction' project. But server file is not reading the data from client instead it just gets terminated with signal SIGCHLD as soon as I write something on client side. Can anyone please suggest me that how should I read data in order to prevent this error?
Thanks in advance.
Below is code snippet of both files.

server_auction.cpp

```
void sig_child(int signo) {
pid_t pid;
int stat;
pid = wait(&stat);
cout<<"child "<<pid<<" terminated with status "<<stat<<endl;
```

}

```
void err_sys(const char* x)    { 
perror(x);      // defined in stdio.h
exit(1);        // indicates unsuccessful program termination
```

}

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//char*product_name[];
int listenfd, connfd, childpid;
int option;     // option =1 if sell otherwise 0 to buy 
int productNo = 0;
ssize_t n;
char buffer[maxBuffer];
socklen_t clilen;
Product obj[maxProduct];
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
listen(listenfd, 5);
cout<<"Starting Auction...."<<endl;
signal(SIGCHLD, sig_child);
for(;;) {
    clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
    if((connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &clilen))<0) {
        err_sys("Accept blocks...exiting");
        break;
    }       
    cout<<"running"<<endl;  
    if((childpid = fork())==0)  {
        cout<<"running2"<<endl; 
        close(listenfd);    
        cout<<"running3"<<endl;         
        read(connfd, buffer, maxBuffer);            //option
        cout<<"buffer:"<<buffer;
        if((option = atoi(buffer))==0) {        // sell
            read(connfd, buffer, maxBuffer);            //cust_name         
            strcpy(obj[productNo].cust_name, buffer);
            read(connfd, buffer, maxBuffer);            //product_id
            strcpy(obj[productNo].product_id, buffer);                  
            read(connfd, buffer, maxBuffer);            //product_details
            strcpy(obj[productNo].product_details, buffer);
            read(connfd, buffer, maxBuffer);            //current_bid               
            obj[productNo].initialBidPrice = atof(buffer);  //initialBidPrice
            obj[productNo].current_bid = atof(buffer);      
            read(connfd, buffer, maxBuffer);            //endTime
            struct tm tm;
            strptime(buffer, "%B/%e/%Y-%H:%M:%S", &tm);   // Aug/1/2017-23:02:51
            time_t t = mktime(&tm); 
            obj[productNo].endTime = t;
            time_t startTime;
            time(&startTime);
            obj[productNo].startTime = startTime;           //startTime         
            exit(0);                
            //close(connfd);    
        }
    }
    productNo++;    
    cout<<"Client Joined: "<<childpid<<endl;
}
close(listenfd);
cout<<"Server terminated";
return 0;
```

}

client_auction.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
char* category[] = {"Vehicle", "Electronics", "Electricals", "Precious"};
char* category0[] = {"Car", "Bike", "Bicycle", "Tricycle", "Taxi", "Auto"};
char* category1[] = {"Laptop", "Desktop", "Cellphone"};
char* category2[] = {"Refrigerator", "Air Conditioner"};
char* category3[] = {"Watch", "Wood", "Iron"};
//char* productID =(char*)malloc(10);
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
char buffer[maxBuffer];
int sockfd, choice, option1, option2, initialBidPrice;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
cout<<"Connection established"<<endl;
//while((fgets(buffer,4096,stdin))!=NULL)  {
cout<<"Want to sell(0) or buy(1) ";
cin>>choice;
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),"%d",choice);
write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);               // option
if(choice == 0) {
    strcpy(buffer,"");              
    cout<<"Enter your name"<<endl;  
    gets(buffer);   
    write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);               // cust_name
    strcpy(buffer,"");              
    cout<<"Choose product category"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Vehicle\n2. Electronics\n 3. Electricals\n4. Precious"<<endl;
    cin>>option1;
    switch(option1) {
        case 1: cout<<"Choose product item in Vehicle Category"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. Car\n2. Bike\n 3. Bicycle\n4. Tricycle\n5. Taxi\n6. Auto"<<endl;              
            cin>>option2;
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),"%d_%d",option1-1, option2-1);
            write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);               //product_id
            strcpy(buffer,"");              
            cout<<"Give your "<<category0[option2-1]<<" details"<<endl;
            gets(buffer);
            write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);
            break;
        case 2: cout<<"Choose product item in Electronics Category"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. Laptop\n2. Desktop\n 3. Cellphone"<<endl;             
            cin>>option2;
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),"%d_%d",option1-1, option2-1);
            write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);               //product_id
            strcpy(buffer,"");                              
            cout<<"Give your "<<category1[option2-1]<<" details"<<endl;
            gets(buffer);
            write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);
            break;
        case 3: cout<<"Choose product item in Electricals Category"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. Refrigerator\n2. Air Conditioner"<<endl;              
            cin>>option2;
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),"%d_%d",option1-1, option2-1);
            write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);               //product_id
            strcpy(buffer,"");                              
            cout<<"Give your "<<category2[option2-1]<<" details"<<endl;
            gets(buffer);
            write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);               // product_details
            break;
        case 4: cout<<"Choose product item in Precious Category"<<endl;
            cout<<"1. Watch\n2. Wood\n3. Iron"<<endl;               
            cin>>option2;
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),"%d_%d",option1-1, option2-1);
            write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);               //product_id
            strcpy(buffer,"");                              
            cout<<"Give your "<<category3[option2-1]<<" details"<<endl;
            gets(buffer);
            write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);
            break;
    }
    cout<<"Enter price to start Bid"<<endl; 
    cin>>initialBidPrice;
    strcpy(buffer,"");              
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),"%d",initialBidPrice);
    write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);           // current_bid
    strcpy(buffer,"");              
    cout<<"Enter closing time and date in format e.g., Aug/1/2017-23:02:51"<<endl;
    gets(buffer);
    write(sockfd, buffer, maxBuffer);
}   
exit(1);close(sockfd);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: The most major flaw in this code is that it doesn't ever call `shutdown()`.  Other major flaws include the use of `gets()` (no good reason to ever call that function, and you're already using `std::cin`, so just use that instead), failure to close sockets (the server parent child will leak sockets), and the fact that the client never reads from the server.  Minor problems include the use of `signal()` (use `sigaction()` instead).  The server apparently receives `SIGCHLD`, and specifies a handler, but the handler code is missing.  Does the server ever call `wait` or `waitpid`?

Comment: If you want a request-response style socket protocol, a way to do this is to `write` from the client until *all* data is written, then `shutdown`, then `read` until EOF, then `close`.  In the server, the opposite order: `read` until EOF, then `write`, then `shutdown`, then `close` (or `exit`).

Comment: I apologize that I copied wrong program for my server file. Now, I've edited it.

Comment: But I've put wait function.

Comment: The signal handler absolutely cannot use `std::cout`, it is not async-signal-safe.  See `man 7 signal` for a list of async-signal-safe functions.  The results from `read` are discarded, this is especially problematic in network programs since it is common to get partial reads or interrupted reads.  There is still no call `shutdown`.